# Where to find Vietnam administrative level 4 shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, tilemill, administrative-boundaries, vietnam

I am new to mapping, and would like to make a custom map using Vietnam's administrative boundaries shape file.  I found a great source at [gadm.org](http://gadm.org/), but it is licensed for non-commercial use only.

I am not currently planning to do anything commercial, but didn't know if there might be another source that is not as restrictive just so that I don't have to worry down the line?  I have looked around and it seems really hard to find.

I looked at OpenStreetMap (OSM), but I think they don't get as specific as the gadm.org files, OSM seems to only get down to rural districts and not the commune level.

I might be wrong about OSM though, as I haven't really delved into it.

Comment: OSM is user driven, so who knows, you will actually have to look at the data/map. Generally the Admin boundaries are shown in purple, just zoom in and look .. I doubt there is anything there, but someone in Vietnam may put them into the database at some time ..

Comment: @MarkC Thanks, I took a look at it, and unfortunately there still isn't that level of detail yet.  Maybe someday I can add them :)

Answer (score 6):

The GADM database of Global Administrative Areas has downloadable shapefile up to level four for Viet Nam. One of the best covered country.

http://www.gadm.org/

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at [openmapsurfer](http://openmapsurfer.uni-hd.de) ... choose a grayscale layer and the boundary overlay, and zoom to the area you are interested in ... boundary visible?

Then try [boundary service](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/) by OSM-user wambacher ... choose the country and province etc from the tree menu at the left. Then you can export the boundary silhouette in different formats.

Comment: I appreciate it, but unfortunately the boundaries on both of these maps go down to the Rural District level (Level 3, I guess?), but don't show the commune boundaries.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Some parts of Vietnam are detailed down to ward level by now, but not all.